# RSS feed: to feed images to your rss

Tags: rss

I have searched around online about feed images to your rss feed. it seems not very popular. is it correct to use  to feed images?

for instance,

```
<enclosure url="http://images.productserve.com/thumb/547/680654.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="3241"/>
```

what is the length in the enclosure elementy?

Answer (score 1):

The enclosure tag is pretty popular for things like podcasts (so, audio files) but I haven't seen it used for images often.

`length` describes the file size in bytes, so it's up to you to pragmatically get that for each image you attach.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure